# How do I enable Windowed mode for Mortal Kombat X?

Tags: mortal-kombat-x

How do I enable Windowed mode for Mortal Kombat X? There's no option available in the PC Video settings or in the Video settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is!

As you can see from this [Screenshot](http://gamingbolt.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/mortal-kombat-x-pc-graphical-settings-options-2.jpg) there is a window mode option.

It only has borderless window mode ( called window mode ), and Full screen as valid options.

Comment: Didn't see it earlier, and this was before I had any of the "DLCs", the Update Packs installed. After getting all of them installed it showed up again, so I guess this solved the issue.